# Multiplayer Java game - program freeze when starting Server via GUI

Tags: java, networking, user-interface

I'm writing a Java GUI multiplayer game.
I have a GUI where user can enter port number and click on "start server" which will initiate game server and bring up another GUI frame. But my program freezes when the button is clicked.
Is it okay to start server using this way or how can I code so that server will be started and waiting for players to be connected and at the same time display another GUI frame (written in a separate class)? Thanks in advance.

```
// part of GUI code

start = new JButton ("Start Game Server");
        start.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
                DEFAULT_PORT = Integer.parseInt(port.getText());
                fgServer.run();
                fgServerFrame = new FishingGameServerFrame();
                //frame.dispose();
            }
        });
```

--

```
// server code

public class FishingGameServer {

    private static int DEFAULT_PORT = 0;

    public void run()
    {

        int port = DEFAULT_PORT;

        port = Integer.parseInt(FishingGameConnectServerFrame.portNumber());
        System.out.println("port #: " + port);

        //setup server socket
        ServerSocket reception_socket = null;

        try {
            reception_socket = new ServerSocket (port);
            System.out.println("Started server on port " + port);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //to get text in GUI frame
            System.out.println("Cannot create server");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for (;;) {
            Socket client_socket = null;

            try {
                client_socket = reception_socket.accept();
                System.out.println("Accepting requests from:" + client_socket.getInetAddress());
            }
            catch (IOException i) {
                System.out.println ("Problem accepting client socket");
            }

            new FishingGameThreadedServer(client_socket);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {

    new FishingGameServer().run();
    }
```

Comment: You have an infinite `for` loop creating `FishingGameThreadedServer` instances, which blocks the event dispatch thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `fgServer.run();`, which eventually calls `client_socket = reception_socket.accept();` within an infinite loop.

This is preventing the Event Dispatching Thread from been able to run, by blocking (once within the neverending `for-loop` and once when using `accept`) it can not process the Event Queue, which is responsible for, amongst other things, processing paint requests.

Swing is a single threaded environment, it is also not thread safe.  This means:

- You should never perform any long running or blocking operations within the context of the EDT and
- All updates and interactions with the UI must be made from within the context of the EDT

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

You could use a `Thread` instead or a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) which provides functionality to more easily publish updates back to the EDT...

Comment: Just beware, if you need to update the UI, you need to make sure that the updates are synchronised with the EDT, use something like `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` for example...