# JLabel and JTextField not updated with setText()

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

In reference to [Multiplayer Java game - program freeze when starting Server via GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638165/multiplayer-java-game-program-freeze-when-starting-server-via-gui) , I used runnable and created a thread to solve the problem I had.

I am now updating JLabel and JTextField but setText() alone is not doing the job. I believe it is due to the thread. I have read a few posts and understand I should be using SwingUtilities.invokeLater for updating of UI.

Here is what I need to do and have tried:

1) ServerFrame (UI JLabel and JTextField to be updated). It has the following method to do the updating. Do I need SwingUtilities.invokeLater here?

```
public static void setStatus (final String status) {
            System.out.println("set status from Fishing connect server frame: " + status);
            player1.setText(status);
            player1.repaint();
}
```

2) Server (This is my game server where I have a method to invoke setStatus in item 1 for updating) and SwingUtilities.invokeLater.

```
public static void setStatus (final String status) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
        public void run()
        {
            FishingGameServerFrame.setStatus(status);
        }
    });
    }
```

3) Item 1 object was initiate through runnable thread in GameConnectServerFrame

```
start.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
                DEFAULT_PORT = Integer.parseInt(port.getText());

                Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        fgServer.run();
                        fgServerFrame = new FishingGameServerFrame();
                    }
                };
                new Thread(r).start();
                frame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
```

The above codes does not have any compilation error but UI still not updated.
May I know which is more appropriate to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater? Item 1 or 2? Or I am doing it all wrong?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: I'm extremely curious about `FishingGameServerFrame.setStatus(status);`. It suggest you are making a static call on a non-existant frame instance. You may need to look into your design a bit. `setStatus` seems like it should be an _instance_ method (not _static_), on which you need to call it on an actual instance of your frame. Maybe that's why you are not seeing any update in the _instance_ frame. For better help, post a [short, complete, runnable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can test out